# createCommand &#039; is appending to query generating Database exception

Tags: exception, yii2

Below is my query:

```
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO `schoolwall-10` SELECT FROM `schoolwall-50` WHERE ID=149")->execute();
```

It is giving me Exception **(Database Exception)** with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `schoolwall-10` SELECT FROM `schoolwall-50` WHERE ID=149&#039;
```

**Updated:**

```
<pre>Exception (Database Exception) &#039;yii\db\Exception&#039; with message &#039;SQLSTATE[42000]:
 Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
 to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;FROM `schoolwall-50` WHERE ID=149
&#039; at line 1
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `schoolwall-10` SELECT FROM `schoolwall-50` WHERE ID=149&#039
; 

in /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:615

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(789): yii\db\Schema-&gt;convertException
(Object(PDOException), &#039;INSERT INTO `sc...&#039;)
#1 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/frontend/models/Wall.php(1317): yii\db\Command-&gt;execute()

#2 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/frontend/models/Wall.php(1245): frontend\models\Wall::saveShareWithCommunities
(Array, Object(frontend\models\SharePopupModal))
#3 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/frontend/models/SharePopupModal.php(58): frontend\models\Wall
::shareWithPrimarySchoolCommunities(Object(frontend\models\SharePopupModal))
#4 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/frontend/controllers/WallController.php(3726): frontend\models
\SharePopupModal-&gt;saveShareWithCommunities()
#5 [internal function]: frontend\controllers\WallController-&gt;actionModalSharePopupSubmit()
#6 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array
(Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(151): yii\base\InlineAction-
&gt;runWithParams(Array)
#8 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller-
&gt;runAction(&#039;modal-share-pop...&#039;, Array)
#9 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(83): yii\base\Module-
&gt;runAction(&#039;wall/modal-shar...&#039;, Array)
#10 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\web\Application-
&gt;handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#11 /var/www/html/OroolaGIT/OroolaPhase1/frontend/web/index.php(18): yii\base\Application-&gt;run()
#12 {main}</pre>
```

Why is &#039 appending to the query? Can anyone please help.

Comment: Show us the complete error message please

Comment: I have updated the question and added the full error stack. Please have a look.

Comment: The real error is about missing * in SELECT ! Not about &#039; ...

Comment: Why question is downvoted? It's a good question why  `&#039` is getting appended ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing *  try adding

```
 \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO `schoolwall-10` 
     SELECT * FROM `schoolwall-50` WHERE ID= 149 ;")->execute();
```

Comment: which Yii2 version you use  ?

Comment: version is 2.0.6-dev

Comment: Me too and i have thoswend createCommad()

Comment: I have also used createCommand() many times in the same project only. But in this case it is giving the exception. It is strange. Not able to find out the issue.